# Why akka-http Unmarshaler returns Future[T] instead of T?

Tags: scala, akka, spray, spray-client, akka-http

Since [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-RC4/scala/http/common/unmarshalling.html) is not ready I'll ask akka maintainers here.

Why akka-http `Unmarshaler` returns `Future[T]` instead of `T` ? Here is my goal. I want to unmarshal class from XML http response similarly how it's done for json. For example I'd like to write

```
Unmarshal(HttpResponse.entity).to[Person]
```

where case class and its unmarshaller looks like this

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

implicit val personUnmarshaller = Unmarshaller[NodeSeq, Person] { _ => xml =>
      Future(Person((xml \\ "name").text, (xml \\ "age").text.toInt))
}
```

It's not gonna compile with `ScalaXmlSupport` supplied with 1.0-RC4 because `Unmarshaller[ResponseEntity,Person]` is not available in the scope. So to trick it I wrote two implicit conversions

```
implicit def xmlUnmarshallerConverter[T](marsh: Unmarshaller[NodeSeq, T])(implicit mat: Materializer): FromEntityUnmarshaller[T] =
  xmlUnmarshaller(marsh, mat)

implicit def xmlUnmarshaller[T](implicit marsh: Unmarshaller[NodeSeq, T], mat: Materializer): FromEntityUnmarshaller[T] =
  defaultNodeSeqUnmarshaller.map(Unmarshal(_).to[T].value.get.get)
```

It works but I don't like ugly `.value.get.get`. Is there more elegant way to implement this ?

Comment: I think it returns a `Future` because the `HttpEntity` can be non-strict and thus the body may be incomplete by the type of receiving the response. That is, in case you have chunked responses, you cannot unmarshal until the response is complete.

Comment: I had a similar issue with the "comfort" of receiving a `Future`. As I remember, the default `HttpEntity` has a known length, but still exposes the content through a `Source[ByteString]`, and that's why you get a `Future` I guess. Nonetheless, I agree with you that it's not very nice when you want to keep it simple.

Comment: Is there a reason to define a `Unmarshaller[NodeSeq, Person]` in the first place? Otherwise, you could directly define an `FromEntityUnmarshaller[Person]` with `defaultNodeSeqUnmarshaller.map(xml => /* the code from your personUnmarshaller*/)`.

Comment: @jrudolph I just wanted to use `NodeSeq` unmarshaler you guys provided which is being used based on `Content-Type`. I guess I could create my own trait instead of using `Unmarshaller[NodeSeq, T]` but I prefer to use as many standard components as possible..

Comment: @jrudolph How should I rewrite `xmlUnmarshaller` to avoid `value.get.get` ? I get an exception because `None,get` is called. Apparently unmarshaller tries to get the value before it's calculated.

Comment: I just meant that you don't need to define an intermediary `Unmarshaller[NodeSeq, Person]` to make use of the standard `NodeSeq` unmashaller. That's why I would suggest to try `implicit val personUnmarshaller: FromEntityUnmarshaller[Person] = defaultNodeSeqUnmarshaller.map(xml => /* the code from your personUnmarshaller*/)`

Comment: @jrudolph I agree. But what if I want to reuse unmarshaller's code not only in processing of http responses but also somewhere else (in tests for example). Having generic solution in form of Unmarshaller[NodeSeq, T] is nice. Why don't you guys make FromEntityUnmarshaller work with Futures like everything else? Current design is inconsistent with your goal to make everything asynchronous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I've implemented my own solution for now but I hope Akka team will make sync/async stuff consistent in the library.

So I created simple clone of `Unmarshaller` which is defined as follows

```
trait SyncUnmarshaller[-A, B] {
  def apply(value: A): B
}

object SyncUnmarshaller {
  def apply[A, B](f: A => B): SyncUnmarshaller[A, B] =
    new SyncUnmarshaller[A, B] {
      def apply(a: A) = f(a)
    }
}

object SyncUnmarshal {
  def apply[T](value: T): SyncUnmarshal[T] = new SyncUnmarshal(value)
}

class SyncUnmarshal[A](val value: A) {
  def to[B](implicit um: SyncUnmarshaller[A, B]): B = um(value)
}
```

Therefore unmarshallers for domain classes will be defined like this

```
implicit val articleBodyUnmarshaller = SyncUnmarshaller[NodeSeq, ArticleBody] { xml =>
  ArticleBody(xml.toString())
}
```

Then there are two implicits for `ScalaXmlSupport` that I already mentioned

```
implicit def xmlUnmarshallerConverter[T](marshaller: SyncUnmarshaller[NodeSeq, T])(implicit mat: Materializer): FromEntityUnmarshaller[T] =
  xmlUnmarshaller(marshaller, mat)

implicit def xmlUnmarshaller[T](implicit marshaller: SyncUnmarshaller[NodeSeq, T], mat: Materializer): FromEntityUnmarshaller[T] = {
  defaultNodeSeqUnmarshaller.map(marshaller(_))
```

That's it. And finally in case you want to use Akka's calls like

`Unmarshal(response.entity).to[Article].map(Right(_))`

You'd need converter from my `SyncUnmarshaller` to akka's `Unmarshaller`

```
implicit def syncToAsyncConverter[A, B](marshaller: SyncUnmarshaller[A, B]): Unmarshaller[A, B] =
  new Unmarshaller[A, B] {
    def apply(a: A)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) =
      try FastFuture.successful(marshaller(a))
      catch { case NonFatal(e) ⇒ FastFuture.failed(e) }
  }
```